# how many times struts 2 action class will initialized?

Tags: struts2

My question is that, how many time action class will initialized in struts 2? I mean that Servlet will initialized only first time and after that on every request new thread will be allocated for new request. Struts 2 action works same like servlet or it will initialized on every new request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new action is created on every new request. If the action has an Action Class then a new instance will be created during that request.